# iOS Unable to play custom sound for remote notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have been trying to implement a custom sound for notifications on iOS.

According to Apple's documentation in example 3 [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html). All we need to do is to ensure that the Push notification payload should be something like:

```
{
"aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    }
}
```

And bingbong.aiff has to be placed in the application bundle.

Also if the App is in active state I was advised to add the following code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bingbong" ofType:@"aiff"];
        theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]error:NULL];

        theAudio.delegate = self;
        [theAudio play];
    }
}
```

`"bingbong.aiff"` is placed in `"SupportingFiles"`

I still donot get the custom sound for remote notification.

I have already gone through other SO Questions similar to this but these are not different from what I am doing.

1. [How to play custom sound file when user get push notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179630/how-to-play-custom-sound-file-when-user-get-push-notification)
2. [Custom sounds in remote notifications iOS 10, swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877803/custom-sounds-in-remote-notifications-ios-10-swift-3)
3. [Change push notification sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37536591/ios-change-push-notification-sound)

Comment: show your script how you are firing notification from server.

Comment: The function `didReceiveRemoteNotification` gets called when the app is open and you receive Push, do you get to hear sound when app is open?

Comment: @iphonic No i dont hear any sound when app is open. The default sound plays when it is in background.

Comment: @Ichthyocentaurs Try put breakpoints in the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and see if you are getting correct file there, may be problem with your sound file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For Default sound:**

According to the apple documentation & guidelines to play default sound you must have to send "Default" value in sound file. Other wise it will not play default sound either.

**For custom sound**:

You need to pass custom sound file name in place of `default` inside your `php script`**.

1. For custom sound file must be exist in your `Xcode` project in
   resources.
2. Make sure sound file duration no longer than 30 seconds. Otherwise
   it will play default sound.
3. And you must add the below key `UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName`
   inside `.plist` file. See below image:

[image]

Comment: will a .mp3 file also work in this case, I tried the above but does not work.

Comment: its working fine with me `.waw` supported here or you can try some more extensions that supported by apple, probably `.mp3` not supported and please double check your php script that may cause of problem.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the way I am placing the file in my project. I just added the entry "UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName" - String - "customsound.aiff". I added the sound file in Xcode to folder Supporting Files by menu option "File">"Add files to Project"

Comment: @Ichthyocentaurs everything is fine here but sound file with extension `.aiff` looks suspicious just use `.wav`, `.caf` (recommended) by converting sound file.

Comment: lastly you can share your php script here so we can help you further.

Comment: let me try with caf

Comment: I dont have access to the server script. On adding breakpoint a po userInfo returns
{
    aps =     {
        alert = "Alert Message";
        sound = "customsound.caf";
        type = 0;
    };
}

Comment: have you converted the file extension or just renamed it, still not playing ?

Comment: converted it using the follwoing command afconvert -f caff -d aacl@22050 -c 1 customsound.aiff customsound.caf

Comment: updated `.plist` file after conversion ? ...try deleting and reinstalling app with apple device. The above solution working fine just double check everything you are almost done.

Comment: Thanks for helping out in such detail. And yes I did change the .plist file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127632/discussion-between-ichthyocentaurs-and-vaibhav).

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `AVPlayer` stuff in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`.

Make sure:

- The sounds length is < 25 seconds
- The file really is in one of the supported formats (aiff, wav, caf)
- The file really exists whitin your bundle (Copy Bundle Resources)
- You registered for push notifications:

  ```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
      let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

      return true
  }
  ```
- The name matches exactly to the file name:

  ```
   {
      "aps" : {
          "alert" : "message",
          "badge" : 1,
          "sound" : "name.aiff"
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I removed the AVPlayer code and already had the permission in applicationDidFinishLaunching: , but still no resolution

Comment: File "Target Membership" was the missing piece for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5** answer, you can do that with AudioToolbox, ideal for short sound clips:

1. Play a default System sound (here's a list of sound codes: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices)

   import AudioToolbox

   AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1103)

2. Play a sound file that you previously dragged into your Xcode project:

   var soundID:SystemSoundID = 0

   let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file_name", ofType: "wav") // or mp3, it depends by your sound file's extension

   let soundURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)

   AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL as CFURL, &soundID)

   AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)